# Is it possible to define a set/list of responses for reusage in open api?

Tags: swagger, response, openapi, http-error

Currently I have something like this:

```
paths: 
    /home
...
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful operation
        401:
          $ref: '#/components/responses/401UnauthorizedDefault'
        404:
          $ref: '#/components/responses/404NotFound'
        502:
          $ref: '#/components/responses/502BadGatewayDefault'
    /sign_up
...
      responses:
        201:
          description: Created
        401:
          $ref: '#/components/responses/401UnauthorizedDefault'
        404:
          $ref: '#/components/responses/404NotFound'
        502:
          $ref: '#/components/responses/502BadGatewayDefault'
```

Is it possible to combine all three error responses and reference them with a $ref?

```
paths:
    /home
...
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful operation
        $ref: '#/components/responses/AllCommonErrorResponses’
    /sign_up
...
      responses:
        201:
          description: Created
        $ref: '#/components/responses/AllCommonErrorResponses’
```

Currently I dont know all the error responses we will use. But there will be a set of shared. If we will extend them later, I dont want to go to every endpoint and adjust the responses.

Comment: Just remove '/responses/' and use anyOf: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/

Comment: @MarkusMeyer I am not sure what you mean. But it seams that you want me to define a list of responses in the path. This is NOT what I am searching for, because once again - I would need to update every single path every time responses are added/ deleted.

Comment: You have to use the 'components'.  '/responses/' is not supported. Please have a look at the shared link. There's an example

Comment: @MarkusMeyer 'components.responses' are supported. I am using them successfully. Take a look here: https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/sgerodes/FesibleX-BE-api-v1/1.0.0#/Error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenAPI v3 does not allow to reference a list of multiple responses.

You can use [specific (e.g., "200") response codes or default](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/) for others.

There is no option to import a standard list of responses and reuse it.